# Deserialize POST data in JSON format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, post

I need to capture/deserialize in C#, using only built-in .NET library, the JSON formatted POST data received from a JavaScript file.

The JSON format is:

```
{"URLs":[{"url_name":"Google", "url_address":"http://www.google.com/"}, {"url_name":"Yahoo", "url_address":"http://www.yahoo.com/"},{"url_name":"FB", "url_address":"http://www.fb.com/"},{"url_name":"MegaSearches", "url_address":"http://www.megasearches.com/"}]}
```

The JavaScript file POSTs the JSON data in http://www.mysite.com/json.aspx and I need to capture the JSON data in .aspx code-behind in C# and save to database.

Comment: How to capture the JSON formatted POST data as a string in C# received from the JavaScript file?

Answer (score 2):

First, create classes to hold the URL data, like this:

```
public class UrlData
{
    public List<Url> URLs {get;set;}
}

public class Url
{
    public string url_address {get;set;}
    public string url_name {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can deserialize the JSON data into the objects, like this:

```
UrlData theUrlData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<UrlData>(jsonResult);
```

Note: `jsonResult` is the JSON data returned from where you are getting the data from.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. Do you know how to "SqlBulkCopy" the "URLs" in SQL database using C#?

Comment: @Ali007 - no I do not, I would recommend starting a new question asking specifically about that, because you will have a SQL specific tag for that question.

Comment: How to capture the JSON formatted POST data as a string ["jsonResult" string] in C# received from the JavaScript file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model class for the incoming JSON data.

```
public class UrlHelper {
    public string url_name {get;set;}
    public string url_address {get;set;}
}
```

In the method in your code behind have the post method accept the data.

```
public YourJsonFormPost(List<UrlHelper> URLs){
    //do your work 
}
```

Comment: How to capture the JSON formatted POST data as a string in C# received from the JavaScript file?